# Can a java application allocate more memory than specified by jvm startup parameters?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, jvm-arguments

Assuming a java application is not using any native libraries. 
Is there a way that it anyway can allocate more memory than specified by jvm startup parameters?

Asking the other way round: Can I rely that a java application will never allocate more memory than restricted by JVM startup parameters?

Comment: A Java *application* will always use more than the maximum memory (heap size) defined by the parameters. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4247735/829571

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. It cannot allocate more memory on the JVM heap, but it can allocate native memory by using `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` or by calling to custom native code.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you always need more memory than the -Xmx specified in your startup script. GC internals, JIT optimization tables, off heap allocations, permgen, thread stacks, etc are all taking their toll.

Answer (score -1):

No, a Java application can not go beyond the size specified by `-Xmx`. It wouldn't make much sense if it could - why bother having `-Xmx` in the first place, then?

I found an interesting [link on Dream.In.Code](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/96263-how-to-set-heap-size/) where a user has given an example of a program that manages to resize itself, but it works by spawning a new JVM process.